# Add awesomium windows form controls to Visual Studio 2015 toolbox

Tags: awesomium

I used Visual Studio 2015 and I open choose item from toolbox and browse awesomium.windows.form.dll.
Then I see four controls that have been selected , But they will not be added to the toolbox.

[image]

Comment: same problem here and i tried everything.. uninstalled and re-installed, removed from GAC..but still i'm not able to use awesomium on vb 2015

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is actually very simple.
The awesomium is not compatible with older versions of .Net and probably your project's target framework is older than .net4.0

You should switch the target project from 3.5 to 4.5 or at least .Net4.0 then you will be able to see all the items of awesomium.